# Javascript selectquery date between

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql, momentjs

I am having trouble on query BETWEEN two dates, what I want is when the user have event will return true and if not then false

The startDate value in my database are `2022-05-01 23:59`

the `date` i get on my form are `14/04/2022 03:32 PM`

```
SELECT assignedTo, startDate FROM Event WHERE assignedTo LIKE '%" + userId + "%' AND startDate BETWEEN " + moment(date).startOf(`day`).format() + " AND " + moment(date).endOf(`day`).format()
```

the value of `moment(date).endOf(`day`).format()` is Invalid date

Comment: What _version_ of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: MySQL @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: What JavaScript library are you using to issue the SQL query?

Comment: Jquery @Tomalak

Comment: jQuery cannot talk to databases. What are you using to talk to the database?

Comment: in mysql use  STR_TO_DATE('14/04/2022','%d/%m/%Y')